How to vertically center a horizontal line to the first line of a multiline paragraph using CSS?
I have a layout where I need to position a horizontal line next to a multiline paragraph. The line should be vertically centered to the first line of the paragraph, not to the entire paragraph.
I've tried using CSS Flexbox to align the items, but it seems to center the line relative to the entire paragraph. How can I adjust the CSS to achieve this alignment?
Here is the HTML and CSS code I have so far:


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.line {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>




Use half the height of one line .5lh


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.line {
  /* new code */
  margin-top: .5lh;
  translate: 0 -50%;
  /**/
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
    <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



You can also simplify the code like below:


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}
.text {
  padding-left: 70px;
}
.text:first-of-type {
  background:
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat
    0 calc(.5lh - 1px)/50px 2px;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</p>
<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</p>




For some reason it doesn't work for me locally even though I have the same code. Can you think of another solution?

@coder - This is the correct way. You would do better to explore why it doesn't work for you, What happens when you try to use this?

I don't know why it doesn't work. Or it doesn't work for me from a font size of 20px. Anything under 20px is vertically centered. I'm using Lato as the font and using Chrome.

@coder - Yeah, general tip when reporting problems: state what does happen, not what doesn't. Where does the line appear when the font is larger?

I didn't set a line-height for the p element. If I explicitly set the line height, then it looks like it is centered vertically.

It looked like setting the line-height helped, but I still have the problem described above.

don't set any line-height/font-size or any font related properties on the p element. You have to set them on the container or an upper element otherwise the trick won't work

That was the reason it didn't work. However, I have a file called styles.css where I have defined Media Queries to set the font size for the  elements. I absolutely need this file. Do you perhaps have another solution that takes into account both the font size and the line height of the  elements?

@coder check the update

@TemaniAfif If you omit the padding-left, you can see that the stroke is not completely vertically centered.

Super lazy option could be using just pseudo with "dash" (/em-dash/three-em-dash) from the very same font-face. In theory, such dash should be defined with vertical typographical balance in mind, usually positioned at or around the middle of the x-height, and naturally adjustable with ex-based transform if the outcome would end up be visually suboptimal when used as a "leader". Entire solution could be a single element with a single pseudo:


p {
 display: flex;
 gap: 1ch;
 &::before {
  content: '⸻';
  color: mark;
  transform: translatey(-.1ex); /* Maybe? */
 }
}

html {
 color-scheme: light dark;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: system-ui;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.



Translating it vertically by +.5ex should put it near baseline, -.5ex should put it near x-height. Most probably will be quite font-dependent, but the general rule that such dash should "look good between regular glyphs" can establish assumption that there should not be super-wild variations of the vertical position relative to baseline between different fonts.
This solution could even have some minor benefits over background variants in some environments:

the "thickness" of this bar should correspond with text strokes in given font-weight,
while being a "real" text, sub-pixel aliasing is more likely to improve the rendering,
since it is present as a flex item, it handles "own" sizing automatically. This could be also drawback, depending on your needs.

Also, to put on the second, third etc. line, it is possible to add white-space: pre and prefix the pseudo content with a line break (\a). And swapping the bar with some fleuron ornament (like ❧) should be intuitive.
Possible drawback is that it is quite important for the font used to support given dash; if the dash would be picked from some fallback font-face, chances are the metrics will most probably be off.
